# Generic with Scala. No ClassTag available for T

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use generics in Scala but in some case it doesn't work to me.

I have define a class as:

```
trait Generic[T <: Product] extends Serializable {

   def start(ssc: StreamingContext, conf: Conf) = {
    val dstream = createDirectStream(...)
    val rdd = dstream.map(x => avroToObject(x.value()))
    execute(rdd)
   }

   def execute(dstreamAvro: DStream[T]): Unit
   def avroToObject(bytes: Array[Byte]): T
}
```

Later, I implement the avroToObject method in a specific class. 
When I try to compile the code I get an error.

```
Error:(36, 30) No ClassTag available for T
    val rddAvro = dstream.map(x => avroToObject(x.value()))
Error:(36, 30) not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[T].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$2.
    val rddAvro = dstream.map(x => avroToObject(x.value()))
```

What is it happening? How could I fix it?

If I changed the declaration of the class by:

```
abstract class Generic[T <: Product](implicit c: ClassTag[T]) extends Serializable {..
```

It works, but I don't understand why, and why it's neccesary that implicit.

Comment: _JVM_ language _generics_ suffer from _type erasure_: that is, all information about generic types is lost at runtime. So, you cannot execute a statement like `val x = new Generic[T]` because when the statement executes, it does know what type `T` is. _Scala_'s solution is to create a `ClassTag[T]` instance that preserves information about `T` at run-time. The `implicit` parameter ensures that the compiler (which always has type information) can pass the information along for use at runtime. `abstract class Generic[T <: Product: ClassTag] extends Serializable {...}` is equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is it happening? How could I fix it?

What is happening is that one of the methods down the execution chain requires an instance of `ClassTag[T]` to be present. Although we don't have the implementation here, I'm assuming that is the `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` method which needs information of type `T` at run time.

This works:

```
abstract class Generic[T <: Product](implicit c: ClassTag[T])
```

Because now that implicit is in scope when you call `createDirectStream`. That is, the compiler is the one which fills in the relevant class tag at compile time for you, and now `createDirectStream` has the relevant implicit in scope to use.